# Changing specific values in a hash given a condition in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash

I have a params hash containing information about an app. This app has a has_many relationship with photos.

Given a specific condition I need to loop though the hash and change one value in each of the photo hashes in the app hash. I need to be able to make this change after the hash has already been created.

Heres one example.

i'm trying to change the keep_photo attribute in every photo to true within app_params.

```
app_params = {"title"=>"Tests", "category_id"=>"1", ...... ", "SFDC_package_url"=>"", "photos_attributes"=>
{"0"=>{"id"=>"45", "name"=>"d", "remote_image_url"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false", "keep_photo"=>"false"}, 
"1"=>{"id"=>"46", "name"=>"g", "remote_image_url"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false", "keep_photo"=>"false"}, 
"2"=>{"id"=>"47", "name"=>"guy", "remote_image_url"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false", "keep_photo"=>"false"}}}
```

how would I do this?

Comment: Why don't you pass the correct value in the first place, while generating the hash? Why not set `keep_photo = true` beforehand? Why change it later?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
app_params["photos_attributes"].values.map! { |x| x["keep_photo"] = "true"}
```

This will update `app_params` as:

```
app_params = {"title"=>"Tests", "category_id"=>"1", ...... ", "SFDC_package_url"=>"", "photos_attributes"=>
{"0"=>{"id"=>"45", "name"=>"d", "remote_image_url"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false", "keep_photo"=>"true"}, 
"1"=>{"id"=>"46", "name"=>"g", "remote_image_url"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false", "keep_photo"=>"true"}, 
"2"=>{"id"=>"47", "name"=>"guy", "remote_image_url"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false", "keep_photo"=>"true"}}}
```

If its in your hand then I would still suggest you to pass the correct value in the first place itself ,i.e., set the correct value `"keep_photo" => "true"` wile generating the `app_params` itself. So, you can avoid these extra changes.

Comment: Could you please accept the answer? If you don't know how to accept an answer then see this:http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235